# Facebook Fresco crashing for pressedStateOverlayImage

Tags: java, android, xml, logcat, fresco

When I used pressedStateOverlayImage for my Drawee it is crashing. I used it just as how they've specified here: [Using Drawees in XML](http://frescolib.org/docs/using-drawees-xml.html#_)

In layout XML:

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
    android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    fresco:fadeDuration="300"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    fresco:actualImageScaleType="focusCrop"
    fresco:placeholderImage="@color/wait_color"
    fresco:backgroundImage="@color/wait_color"
    fresco:pressedStateOverlayImage="@color/red"
    />
```

In colors XML:

```
<color name="red">#ff0000</color>
```

Java:

```
Fresco.initialize(MainActivity.this);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://image3.redbull.com/rbcom/010/2015-04-05/1331715252374_2/0010/1/1400/933/2/red-bull-show-run-2015-india-hyderabad.jpg");
SimpleDraweeView draweeView = (SimpleDraweeView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
draweeView.setImageURI(uri);
```

Logcat:

```
  12645-12645/frescodemo.technicosa.com.frescodemo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: frescodemo.technicosa.com.frescodemo, PID: 12645
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{frescodemo.technicosa.com.frescodemo/frescodemo.technicosa.com.frescodemo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2237)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:240)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at frescodemo.technicosa.com.frescodemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2201)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:240)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at frescodemo.technicosa.com.frescodemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2201)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.facebook.drawee.drawable.ArrayDrawable.mutate(ArrayDrawable.java:182)
            at com.facebook.drawee.generic.GenericDraweeHierarchy.<init>(GenericDraweeHierarchy.java:278)
            at com.facebook.drawee.generic.GenericDraweeHierarchyBuilder.build(GenericDraweeHierarchyBuilder.java:431)
            at com.facebook.drawee.view.GenericDraweeView.inflateHierarchy(GenericDraweeView.java:278)
            at com.facebook.drawee.view.GenericDraweeView.<init>(GenericDraweeView.java:74)
            at com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView.<init>(SimpleDraweeView.java:58)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at 

android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:240)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at frescodemo.technicosa.com.frescodemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2201)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Which part of the logcat should I be looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake:

Have to use an `overlayImage` first to use `pressedStateOverlayImage`

```
fresco:overlayImage="@drawable/overlay"
fresco:pressedStateOverlayImage="@color/red"
```

Comment: I am using fresco overlayImage attribute for adding ripple effect on top of image. Ripple effect is showing properly but hot spot of touch is always in center. Did you set ripple effect by using overlayImage attribute?. If yes re you able add hot spot to it?

Comment: Sorry I haven't used ripple effect.